# Terraform API Gateway not deploying

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

In my api gateway deployment resource, I've added triggers to trigger deployment. I made a dummy commit to update one of the integration resources but it's still not deploying

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "api_deployment" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  stage_name  = "production"

  triggers = {
    redeployment = sha1(jsonencode([
      aws_api_gateway_resource.slack.id,
      aws_api_gateway_resource.interactions.id,
      aws_api_gateway_resource.events.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.slack_events.id,
      aws_api_gateway_method.slack_interactions.id,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.integration, 
      aws_api_gateway_integration.interaction_resource_integration,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.slack_resource_integration,
      aws_api_gateway_integration.events_resource_integration
    ]))
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "stage" {
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.api_deployment.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  stage_name    = "production"
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "not deploying" mean? Are there any errors? If so, please add them to the question.

Comment: In the terraform logs, there are no errors. However, when I check the console, url is missing for the api gateway

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot of what is missing to the question?

Comment: Have you tried the answer you got? I don't think you would have to edit any triggers.

Comment: Hi, I finally fixed the issue, it was the integration resource. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have both stage_names configured as "production". I think you could probably take out the `stage_name = "production"` in the `aws_api_gateway_deployment` resource block since best practice is to use a separate stage block, as you did.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_deployment

Comment: Hi @cybershady, do I have to edit any one of the triggers again to trigger redeployment?